# How to use mean_squared_error loss in tensorflow session

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I am new to tensorflow

In a part of a code for a tensorflow session, there is :

```
 loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits_v2(
                    logits=net, labels=self.out_placeholder, name='cross_entropy')
                self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss, name='mean_squared_error')
```

I want to use `mean_squared_error` loss function for this purpose. I found this loss function in tensorflow website:

```
tf.losses.mean_squared_error(
labels,
predictions,
weights=1.0,
scope=None,
loss_collection=tf.GraphKeys.LOSSES,
reduction=Reduction.SUM_BY_NONZERO_WEIGHTS
)
```

I need this loss function for a regression problem.

I tried:

```
loss = tf.losses.mean_squared_error(predictions=net, labels=self.out_placeholder)
self.loss = tf.reduce_mean(loss, name='mean_squared_error')
```

Where `net = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases`

However, I'm not sure if it's the correct way.

Comment: just drop the argument `name` then

Comment: @JonathanR Right, but every other thing is OK?

Comment: I cannot tell you without seeing what is in `net` or `self.out_placeholder` but if they are fine, yes it's OK

Comment: @JonathanR it apparently works! thanks and net is net = tf.matmul(input_tensor, weights) + biases

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all keep in mind that cross-entropy is mainly used for classification, while MSE is used for regression.

In your case cross entropy measures the difference between two distributions (the real occurences, called labels - and your predictions)

So while the first loss functions works on the result of the softmax layer (which can be seen as a probability distribution), the second one works directly on the floating point output of your network (which is no probability distribution) - therefore they cannot be simply exchanged.

Comment: I know, and I want to change it for a regressin problem! but I don't know how. please guide me how to change it to mse

Comment: Tell me more about what you are actually doing so I can help you. Are you classifying images? Predicting temperature? etc.

Comment: I'm predicting gold price according to 28 days before. That's a regression problem.

Comment: Then your `predictions` is the output of your last layer (which should output 1 real value), while labels should be the gold price at time n that you are trying to predict. Because you usually do batch-training, both labels and predictions should be vectors (each index n represents one tupel of (output, label))